# How can we do a test verification for a non-normal distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, methodology, ab-test

I know that if we have a normally distributed distribution we can verify whether it's significant with the rates and our normal approximation. For instance with the following segments:

```
        segment 1   segment 2
count   1537.000000 1358.000000
mean    80.798308   110.098675
std     143.332854  208.989661
min     2.000000    3.000000
25%     20.000000   30.000000
50%     30.000000   42.500000
75%     60.000000   90.000000
max     1550.000000 3100.000000
```

With the following distribution:

[image]

I found that the difference is significant with the t-test:

```
>>>import scipy.stats as stats
>>>stats.ttest_rel(df_segment_1.sample(1358), df_segment_2.sample(1358))
Ttest_relResult(statistic=-4.403644781798156, pvalue=1.1480571828377323e-05)
```

pvalue is super low, so segment 2 is significatively upper than segment1. I wanted to validate wether it was significant with the following homemade test. I generate the normal distributions from the two populations means and standard deviations and get 10000 their means:

```
n = 10000
means_a = norm(mean_a, std_a).rvs(n)
means_b = norm(mean_b, std_b).rvs(n)
b_better = (means_b > means_a).mean()
print(f"B is better than A {b_better:0.1%} of the time")
```

And the results are:

```
B is better than A 54.2% of the time
```

But my original distribution is not normal ...

So I am not sure if I can use it as verification as the original distribution is a non-normal distribution? If so, how can we do a test verification for a non-normal distribution?

Comment: I do not see anything in your code that assumes normality. What do you think assumes so?

Comment: As @Dave noted, your comparison method works for any distribution. Moreover, your comparison criterion, the *mean*, actually *is* normally distributed (approximately) according to the central limit theorem. Therefore, even testing for a "significant" difference with a t-test works approximately.

Comment: @cdalitz I understand but then, I see that the second distributions mean is above the second only 54% of the time. I didn't found it as significative as the p-value of my t-test ... So I was thinking that it was only for validating the results of tests that were done one for normal distributions

Comment: @revolucion-for-monica If comparing values makes any sense, then you apparently have *paired data*, i.e. you measure *two* values for each instance. In this case you must use a paired t-test (parameter `paired=TRUE`). What does this test say?

Comment: Unfortunately `paired` parameter doesn't exists in [`stats.ttests_ind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) According to this article _To conduct the paired sample t-test, one needs to use the `stats.ttest_rel()` method._ but it seems I need to have two populations of same size.

Comment: Yes, you need pairs of observations, so equal sample (not population) sizes are a must. If you do not have equal sample sizes but think you have pairing, something funky is going on. Please explain that in more detail.

Comment: Okay, I sampled 1358 = 100% of the second segment and the same number for the first and found that the difference was signed using the paired t-test. What method should I use to verify my results are correct because mine based on the normal distributions based on the means doesn't seem very accurate as B is better than A only 54.2% of the time

Comment: And why should i use `stats.ttest_rel()`, a method that calculates the t-test on **two related** samples of scores rather than `ttest_ind` that calculates the t-test on two independent samples of scores. I thought my two segments (donations with a form A and donations with a form B) were independant?

Comment: From your explanation, you have simulated two independent samples, which means that you must *not* use a paired t-test. I am at a loss, though, what you mean by "sample B is greater than sample A x percent of the time". This contention requires that you have paired data, i.e., $A_i$ and $B_i$ are not independent, but $A_i$ and $A_j$ are (for $i\neq j$), where the index $i,j$ stands for the measurement number (or time).

Comment: With `stats.ttest_rel()`, a method that calculates the t-test on two related samples of scores, the pvalue is super low, so segment 2 is significatively upper than segment1. I wanted to validate whether it was significant with the homemade test I did in python at the bottom of the question: I generate the normal distributions from the two populations' means and standard deviations and get 10000 their means. It tells me that B is better than A 54.2% of the time and I don't find it very significant... I guess this is because the original distributions are truncated and right-skewed. What to try?

Comment: I wanted to say that the mean of the normal distribution generated with samples of B from its parameters is 54.2% higher than the mean of the same of A, @cdalitz . I don't find this significant whereas the t-test found that the difference is significant. So I guess that I shouldn't generate data from a normal distribution to validate the findings of the t-test, so how can I validate the findings of the t-test?

Comment: Can you post the original data, or a link to it?